# Authorized JavaScript origins

Tags: javascript, php

i am developing an email service and want to connect with google account, is it possible to use my localhost as Authorized JavaScript origins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Enable the Google+ API

```
http://localhost:4567
https://myproductionurl.example.com
```

Step 2: Set up the JavaScript quick-start app

```
git clone https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript.git
wget https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript/archive/master.zip -o gplus-quickstart-javascript.zip
unzip gplus-quickstart-javascript.zip
cd gplus-quickstart-javascript
```

Step 3: Run the quick-start app

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/javascript):

> In the Authorized JavaScript origins field, enter the origin for your app. You can enter multiple origins to allow for your app to run on different protocols, domains, or subdomains. You cannot use wildcards. In the example below, the second URL could be a production URL.

```
http://localhost:4567
https://myproductionurl.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so. Be sure to enter your public ip adress in the credentials though. You can find that by requesting a site like [whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)

It also needs a http:// or https:// prefix so you would end up with something like `http://97.987.98.987`